# Instagram API, pending review for new app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have submit a app for review before two weeks for basic permission. it's still showing on pending review. Can anyone tell me, instagram pause the app review for new app. If app review status goes in pause so when instagram start again to app review.

Comment: Are you trying to use the old-fashion Instagram API ?

Comment: yes, we are using old instagram api. my simple requirement is get media of logged in user through this api:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]

Comment: I have same problem ! no one knows

Comment: Nice one Zuck. Same problem.

Comment: Same problem. It has been almost a month for me. @vineetpal could you get approval?

Comment: No, its under pending review for last one two month.

Comment: As best I can tell they have stopped taking new app approvals.

Comment: Same issue.  Pending for more than 2 weeks with zero updates.  Why allow us to submit new apps if they aren't going to let us know if / when they might ever get approved?

Comment: @vineetpal, please my answer if correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exacerbated by the fact that Facebook put a pause on reviewing any new applications last Monday as it tries to shore up data privacy safeguards in the wake of Cambridge Analytica. (Cambridge Analytica is a data mining, analysis, and brokerage company.)

The moratorium on app submissions extends to Instagram’s new Graph API, but wouldn’t explain anything about the API limits. So Instagram is breaking old apps while not allowing developers to submit new, compliant ones.

Reference link: https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/